# Communicate between App Delegate and VC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I have a method in my app delegate that updates the badge count for the app's icon.  I want this method to also update something in another VC which is visible throughout the app (like a notification center) I have.

How can I do this?

The method looks like:

```
- (void) remedyERxInterface:(RSeRxInterface *)eRxInterface 
             didSynchronize:(BOOL)success pendingMessageCounts:(NSDictionary *)pendingMessageCounts {

    NSInteger messageTotal = 0;
    NSInteger refillRequests = [[pendingMessageCounts objectForKey:kRSQueuesRefillCount] intValue];
    NSInteger problems = [[pendingMessageCounts objectForKey:kRSQueuesProblemCount] intValue];
    NSInteger messages = [[pendingMessageCounts objectForKey:kRSQueuesMessageCount] intValue];

    if (0) {
        if (self.eRxModuleInboxMessageCount) {
            messageTotal = refillRequests + problems + messages;
        } else {
            messageTotal = refillRequests + problems + messages + 12;
        }
    } else {
        //Production
        messageTotal = refillRequests + problems + messages;
    }

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = messageTotal;
    self.eRxModuleInboxMessageCount = messageTotal;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a notification center call from whatever calls your badge update method?

Comment: That sounds good, could you provide more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention a notification center. Have you looked into using NSNotifications through the NSNotificationCenter? It is ideal for a central entity to broadcast information without knowing who listens. You can just register your view controllers for these notifications with callbacks which will be called synchronously.

Comment: Ok, so I can setup a notification when this method is called and pass the interger `messageTotal` to my other VC.  How exactly would I do that in code? Thanks

Comment: If you look at the NSNotification programming guide, it's quite thorough and straightforward, you can pass a userInfo dictionary with your notification containing an NSNumber with the integer you want to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

If some information needs to be visible throughout the app, create a manager class that is responsible for storing the information.  Create a convenience method to access a shared instance of this class.  When an event occurs that means you have to update the information, tell the shared instance about the event.  For all parts of your user interface that need to display this information, use Key-Value Observing (KVO) against the shared instance to be notified when any of its properties change.

Comment: I already have all the code figure out.  I just need to have it update a badge on a UIButton in another VC when this method is run from the app delegate.